# How to wait for observable resolve from different components in Angular

Tags: angular, asynchronous, angular-httpclient

I have a question regarding observables.

Lets say I have a Service with an observable and I have two different components that subscribe to that observable. The Observable itself does a Backend query.

Currently I have a problem, that with the same input both of the observables in the separate components send out independent network requests with the same input param.

Is there way to make it so, that if these 2 observable called are made when one of them is executing, the second one will wait for the first to finish and use that result?

I am using httpClient and angular 5 at the moment

Any suggestions or design patterns are welcome :)

Comment: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/concat.html

Comment: @bugs I think this would not be an option, since the two calls with the same param would come from different components, how would I concat them?

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 1):

Please use service as a singleton. This can be done by configuring service in provider list in the root module.

In the service, have an observable as a variable.

Call the same service method from both components.

The service method should check if observable variable is already set. If set, return the variable. If not set, call the httpclient function and assign results to the observable variable, and return the same.

I hope this logic should work.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually the normal behavior of the `HTTP` observables as they are Cold.
When a cold `observable` has multiple `subscribers`, the whole data stream is re-emitted for each `subscriber`. Each subscriber becomes independent and gets its own stream of data

To  Avoid Duplication of HTTP Requests you can use [`shareReplay`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/multicasting/sharereplay.html) operator.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {shareReplay,tap}from 'rxjs/operators';
@Injectable()
export class ShareService {

public response$:Observable<any>;
constructor(private httpc:HttpClient)
{
  this.sendRequest();
}
public sendRequest()
{

 this.response$= this.httpc.get('url').
    pipe(tap(res=>{console.log('called');return res;}),shareReplay(1))

}
fetchData()
{

return this.response$;
}
}
```

**component1:**

```
 constructor(service:ShareService)
  {

     service.fetchData().subscribe(result=>{
     console.log(result);

    })
```

**component2:**

```
 constructor(service:ShareService)
  {

     service.fetchData().subscribe(result=>{
     console.log(result);

    })
```

[`Further Reading`](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-http/)
**[`Live Demo`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-isfka6)**

Answer (score 0):

I would like to thanks all of the suggested answers, as they guided me towards lookin at RXJS documentation a little bit deeper.

So what I found and what others basically said here before, the observable was cold. So what that means is that every time the observable is subscribed to a new request is sent.

To make it hot, so subscribers would wait for the response I used the share() operator from RxJS.

Please more detailed use cases and explanations from the following blog posts:

https://blog.strongbrew.io/how-share()-can-reduce-network-requests/ and https://blog.novanet.no/angular-pitfall-multiple-http-requests-with-rxjs-and-observable-async/

Thanks again to Vikas and Rakesh for pointing me in the right direction :)